# Re-enable click in element where clicks are disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a panel which is opened when a button is clicked, I am then closing the panel if the document is clicked.

I use code which ignores the panel element and it's contents if they are clicked as part of the document click.

Issue I'm having is that I have a close button inside the container which I am specifying to be ignored!

Can anyone offer a workaround to this so that the button inside is still functional?

```
 UtilityBar = (function() {
    var _self = {},
        recentPanel = $('#utils_recent'),
        recentButton = $('#utils_show_recent');
    function init() {
        bindEvents();
    }
    function bindEvents() {
        recentButton.on('click', toggleRecent);
        $(document).on('click', function(event) {
            if (!$(event.target).closest('.utils').length) {
                closePanels();
            }
        });   
        // This obviously doesn't work
        $('.utils_close').on('click', closePanels);
    }
    function toggleRecent(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        recentPanel.toggleClass('is_open');
    }
    function closePanels() {
        recentPanel.removeClass('is_open');
    }
    _self = {
        init: init
    };
    return _self;
})();
$(function() {
    UtilityBar.init();
});
```

Here is a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/kptwc82z/4/

Comment: I don't follow you. The fiddle works like I'd expect (click "open" to open the bar, click the document or "close" to close it again)

Comment: Click to close works in your example

Comment: Seems this is working fine.